# R funtion for website table into dataframe

Tags: r, rcurl, jsonlite

I want to download a table from a database that contains  a set of information in a table format

```
The website https://membranome.org/species/1
```

I tried Rcurl,rlist, rvest  and jsonlite but i cannot make it  for example jsonlite code

```
a <- fromJSON("https://membranome.org/species/1")

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>  
                     (right here) ------^
```

I want the table of content from the website for data analysis  in a data frame format which i can furtherly  write and save in csv file format

For example my expected output

```
Family  protein Name  Protein ID  Localization Topology TM etc
aaaa       bbbb           123        2             152   58 ....
cccc       dddd            234       3              158   60 ....
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly was the code you tried? What were the problems with the code?

Comment: @MrFlick i have followed some stack basic codes for url extraction  and unfortunately messed with it

Answer (score 0):

`rvest` might not work on your case since the table is not on the page source. An alternative approach might be using *XMLHttpRequests* (XHR) to pull json data. Then parse that json into R object (dataframe or list) using json parser package like `jsonlite`.

Follow [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60892092/3713478) to get started.